# How to develop for SQL Server 2008 using 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2008, version, compatibility, sql-server-2012

When I use MSBuild 4 I can target .NET Framework 3.5 and older versions, and all features available only on the version 4 will not be available on that project.

I would like to do a similar thing in SQL Server 2012. Can I configure a database in it to behave similary to a SQL Server 2008 one? Can I make one database to not accept commands only available to SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Not really. See [Does the compatibility level for sql server work reliably for scripts?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6731) for some related discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Compatability Level within the database properties.

1. Right Click the Database
2. Click `Properties`
3. Select `Options`
4. Choose the `Compatability Level`

   - 110 = SQL 2012
   - 100 = SQL 2008 & 2008 R2
   - 90 = SQL 2005

This option only affects the behaviour of this particular database, not the entire server.  It should be regarded only as partial backwards compatibility.  **If your intention is for SQL Server to treat this database as a SQL 2008 database, then the best way to do this would be to run it within SQL 2008 rather than SQL 2012.**

Here is a very detailed explanation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680(v=sql.110).aspx

**T-SQL**

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = { 90 | 100 | 110 }
```

Comment: It also doesn't prevent use of a whole load of 2012 specific features